# Best method of sweeping monero private keys without rescanning the blockchain for a balance?

Tags: privatekey, balance, sweep-transaction

I'm creating a tipping type app where I issue unique monero private keys for all my users like how an exchange has a different monero address for each user. I'm sure they are just using a payment id for each user while all funds goto the same wallet.

But in my case, I'm not using a payment ID. How can I **sweep all coins** from these addresses to my own without a rescan of the blockchain for each address? FYI, I also have a copy of the private keys for my users.

- Scanning for an updated balance takes awhile. Can this be skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to make a transaction, the wallet must know how much it contains.

The approach for you would be to only scan from when the user made the transaction by specifying a restore height or date. Allowing you to only scan i.e. the last 10 blocks.

This technique only works if you are sure that each user only used an address from a specific moment. You can couple it with a remote node to allow multiple scans from multiple wallets without being bothered by the download speed.

However, I still would advise you to really consider the option of a single address as this entire process becomes automated.

Keep yourself informed you still use separated addresses as *sub-addresses* may be useful for your case once these become a thing.

Comment: My setup is generating a unique address for each user where they control the private keys. So having just 1 private key I control isn't going to work even if I issue a payment id for each user. My app involves working with a "shared" private key.